# MS Access + Oracle Pass-Through SQL with DBLink to another database

Tags: oracle, ms-access, dblink, pass-through

In Microsoft Access (I'm using 2013) is there a way to perform a SQL Pass-through query to Oracle where the query contains a DB Link to another Oracle DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered my own question.  You can but it is dependent on access rights to the databases.  For me, I just needed to connect to my ODBC and in my sql statement set up my db link via [db name].[table name]@[Server name] format.